# One-to-many hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, one-to-many

I have this relation one-to-many.
This is my ONE table.

```
private Set<Images> imagesContainer = new HashSet<Images>(0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "container")
public Set<Images> getImagesContainer() {
    return this.imagesContainer;
}

public void setImagesContainer(Set<Images> imagesContainer) {
    this.imagesContainer = imagesContainer;
}
```

And this is my MANY table:

```
private Container container;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_container", nullable = false)
public Container getContainer() {
    return this.container;
}

public void setContainer(Container container) {
    this.container = container;
}
```

How can i insert, with hibernate, a new container with MANY container.
I'll try this:

```
...
Set<Images> images=new HashSet<Images>();
images.add(img1);
images.add(img2);

Container c = new Container();
c.setImagesContainer(images);
....

@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void save(Container c){
   getHibernateTemplate().save(c);
}
```

Don't work !!! I got "nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not insert:..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specify `mappedBy = "container"` in the `Container` entity , the owner of the relationship is the `Images` entity .That means that hibernate will determine the  relationship between `Container` and `Images` entity using `image.getContainer()`

Because you did not set any container instances to the container property of  all the `images` instances in your code snippet , `image.getContainer()` returns `NULL` and thus hibernate will think that  all the `image` instances are not associated with any `Container` instance . It will insert `NULL` to the `Container` table  's `id_container` column which does not allow NULL (`nullable = false`) , hence errors occur.

To solve the problem , you should set the `container` property of the `Image` instance:

```
Container c = new Container();
img1.setContainer(c);
img2.setContainer(c); 
session.save(c);
```

Comment: The error occurred for others problems. I use your solutions or my solutions: 1 record in Container and 0 record in Images, without errors.

Comment: PS: Container hasn't ID because this is an INSERT, not UPDATE